# The correct syntax of this JSON statement to pass array fields to variables in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I need help with the correct JSON syntax in Swift for being able to read a particular array passed from a php script that contains Strings and Integers.

I want to split this array up into variable within swift.

The output of the array in browser with example of `player_id=2`:

> {"totalWins":10,"totalDraws":6,"totalLosses":3,"winPercentage":"52.63%","goalsScored":40,"goalsConceded":30,"goalDifference":10}

This is my Swift 3.0 function that calls the API:

```
    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/getTotalsStats.php?");
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);

    request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.httpMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "player_id=\(self.playerId)";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in


        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {

                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                do{
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]
                    print (json as Any)

                    if let arr = json?["totalWins"] as? [[String:String]] {
                        self.newNumberWins = arr.flatMap { Wins($0) }
                        print (self.newNumberWins)

                    }


                } catch{
                    print(error)
                }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

The error I am getting in Xcode is:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

With my limited knowledge of what's going on I'm guessing it is something to do with not assigning / getting the 'types' correct (i.e String, AnyObject, Dictionary).

Also, I think I need to use .flatMap but I'm struggling to put all the pieces together.  Can someone help me please?

To clarify this is the output of my JSON in browser with example of `player_id=2`:

> {"totalWins":10,"totalDraws":6,"totalLosses":3,"winPercentage":"52.63%","goalsScored":40,"goalsConceded":30,"goalDifference":10}

I have tested the JSON in Chrome REST client and this was the output:

[image: Screen Shot 2016-11-08 at 17.44.35.png]

It has been suggested that I convert the data being received by the app to a string. However I don't know how to do this.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be immense.

Comment: *Invalid value around character 0* means the received data is no JSON

Comment: You could convert your data to a string, print it, and run it against jsonlint to see if it's valid.

Comment: I have updated the question with the php script if that helps in any way

Comment: You need to do what @Frankie suggested so you can see what you are actually getting back from the server. It's not what you think.

Comment: Thanks Maddy - how do I go about that?  (I realised that I had actually posted the wrong Swift script so I have updated that also)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is there, but there is also html in your response.

The best solution is to convert your data to a string, print it, and run it against jsonlint to see if it's valid.  Your app is receiving something different than you expect it to.

**EDIT:**

I can't say it any clearer than this:

[image]

Comment: I've just changed _POST to _REQUEST.  If you could do that again and see if you get what you expected... thanks

Comment: Haha, you don't need me to do it, you can put it into your own browser just as easily!  But anyway, it's the same.  From the looks of the notice you may want to check line 6 of getDetails.php eh?  I'm not a php developer so I can't help you much further.

Comment: http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/getTotalsStats.php?player_id=2 is the correct URL

Comment: You're missing the point.  Post that url in your browser and you get the same error and message.  Fix that error in your php file and you're likely to get just the valid JSON in your iOS app.

Comment: it outputs correctly in my browser - that is the yellow block at the beginning of my post

Comment: Well I gave you what it output on mine... so for whatever that's worth.  More importantly, you haven't taken the step to figure out what your app is receiving.  You need to convert your data to a string and print it out and post it in your question.  You can google how to do that in a couple minutes.

Comment: sorry Frankie, I think at the time it was set to _POST and not _REQUEST hence why it didn't output properly.

Comment: Updated with screen shot of request made with Chrome REST client

Comment: Thanks Frankie for investigating this for me I appreciate it.  I have posted an image of what I get when I test the url.  Why do you think its different results for us?  Also, what website/service is that you use to test like that?

Comment: Don't know.  Try clearing your cache or using the Chrome REST client.  Or, heaven forbid, convert the data response in the app to a string and print it out.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to convert the data response in the app to a string and print it out?  I did ask this in response to Maddy first suggesting I tried your initial suggestion over an hour ago but I didn't get an answer.

Comment: Google it, look in the Apple Docs, or post another question.  It's incredibly straightforward.  Actually don't post another question, it's surely already available somewhere on SO.

Comment: You'll have to excuse my ignorance in this, I am new to Swift and development so still trying to muddle through.  Although that would be an incredibly simple task for you it takes me a little while longer.

Comment: No one is judging your ignorance.  Take as long as you need.  SO is here to help solve problems but not write code for you to copy and paste.

Comment: I think I have done as you suggested and converted the data to string.  I have printed the result in my browser and shown the result in the question. Thanks

Comment: Convert the data being received by the **app** to a string.  `(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?)`  That data!

Comment: Am I along the right lines trying: let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

Comment: What happened when you actually put it in the code and tried to run it?  That will tell you if you're along the right lines.

Comment: Expression implicitly coerced from 'NSString?' to Any

Comment: Frankie- i know that. I have tried all 3 options and I still get the same error.  With all due respect if you cannot offer a direct and immediate solution please don't comment as I am concerned someone with a solution may just think 'the issue is in hand'.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your response header is set with content-type = "application/json"

Comment: Thanks, just made that addition to the php script, though it hasn't had any effect

Comment: request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")